# Azure Dev Ops warnings inline shell script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

## Problem

I am running an inline shell script on a remote machine via SSH in an Azure Dev Ops pipeline. Depending on some conditions, running the pipeline should throw a custom warning.

The feature works, albeit in a very twisted way: when running the pipeline, the warning **always** appears. To be more precise:

- If the condition it not met, the warning appears once.
- If the condition is met, the warning appears twice.

The example below should give a clear illustration of the issue.

## Example

Let's say we have the following `.yaml` pipeline template. Please adapt the `pool` and `sshEndpoint` settings for your setup.

```
pool: 'Default'

steps:

- checkout: none
  displayName: Suppress regular checkout

- task: SSH@0
  displayName: 'Run shell inline on remote machine'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'user@machine'
    runOptions: inline
    inline: |
     if [[ 3 -ne 0 ]]
     then
       echo "ALL GOOD!"
     else
      echo "##vso[task.logissue type=warning]Something is fishy..."
     fi
    failOnStdErr: false
```

### Expected behavior

So, the above bash script should echo `ALL GOOD!` as 3 is not 0. Therefore, the warning message should not be triggered.

### Current behavior

However, when I run the above pipeline in Azure Dev Ops, the step log overview says there is a warning:

[image: Step Log Overview]

The log itself looks like this (connection details blacked out):

[image]

So even though the code takes the `ALL GOOD!` code path, the warning message appears. I assume it is because the whole bash script is echoed to the log - but that is just an assumption.

## Question

How can I make sure that the warning only appears in the executed pipeline when the conditions for it are satisfied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [the SSH task logs the script to the console prior to executing it](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SshV0/ssh.ts#L107-L108). You can probably trick the log parser:

```
HASHHASH="##"
echo $HASHHASH"vso[task.logissue type=warning]Something is fishy..."
```

[I'd consider it a bug that the script is appended to the log as-as. I've filed an issue.](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14395) (Some parsing does seem to take place as well)...

Comment: Hey! That is a nice trick, but it seems to suppress the warning alltogether - which is also not what I want. I'd still like to see the warning appear if the condition is met.

Comment: It works with a small correction though: `echo $HASHHASH"vso[task.logissue type=warning]Something is fishy..."`
If you make that change, I can accept your answer ;)